# Audio duration returns 0.0

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, duration, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

Im trying to get the duration of the audio i've recorded using AVAudioRecorder (.m4a format) but the following code prints out "0.0" :

```
    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: myAudioFileURL)
    let audioDuration = asset.duration
    print(Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration)))
```

What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do
    {
        let avAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOfURL:recordedAudioURL)
        duration = avAudioPlayer.duration
        let ms  = Int((duration%1)*1000)
        let sec = Int(duration%60)
        let minutes = Int(duration / 60) % 60
        let hours = Int(duration / 3600)
        recordedAudioDuration.text = (NSString(format: "Dur: %0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d.%0.3d",hours,minutes,sec,ms)) as String
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Cheers. Worked perfectly